# save() domain in grails-plugin project

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class

Created a domain class,  Student.

Created a controller, in controller called

```
def p = new Student()
p.save()
```

It says

```
No signature of method: hazelgrails.Student.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: save(), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map), wait(), any(), wait(long). Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: hazelgrails.Student.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: save(), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map), wait(), any(), wait(long)
```

Are domain CRUD operations not allowed in plugin project?

I am lazy developer, do not want to create a test application and packge/install plugin everytime I code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are domain CRUD operations not allowed in plugin project?

They are. Are you sure you've put your `Student` class under the `domain` directory?

> I am lazy developer, do not want to create a test application and packge/install plugin everytime I code.

You can avoid this overhead by loading the plugins [in-place](http://johnrellis.blogspot.com/2010/03/grails-inplace-plugin-tip.html)

Comment: Yes they are in domain directory. I created them with grails create-domain-class. May it be a bug in 2.0.1

Comment: in-place plugin development. Although still save() do not work, in place  fits to me, thx.

Answer (score 1):

If the class name in the file does not match the name of the groovy file you will get this same error. In my case it was MyImage.groovy versus class Myimage (lowercase I).  This seems like a bug in Grails 2.0.3 and lower.